# Confused on creation of binary sysfs entry

Tags: c, linux-kernel, sysfs

On kernel 4.0, when stepping through the kernel source for `sysfs_create_bin_file`, I notice it passes to `sysfs_add_file(kobj->sd, &attr->attr, true);` The `&attr->attr` being the `struct attribute` struct within the `bin_attribute` struct.

This makes sense until I visit `sysfs_add_file_mode_ns`, which is directly called from `sysfs_add_file`, and on [line #277](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.0/source/fs/sysfs/file.c#L277) sets temp variable `stuct bin_attribute *battr = (void*)attr;`

Isn't this pointing to a `struct attribute` at this point, how is it resolving this to the proper struct (due to the call to `sysfs_add_file` using `&attr->attr` on [line #483](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.0/source/fs/sysfs/file.c#L483))?

Code

```
int sysfs_create_bin_file(struct kobject *kobj,
              const struct bin_attribute *attr)
{
    BUG_ON(!kobj || !kobj->sd || !attr);

    return sysfs_add_file(kobj->sd, &attr->attr, true);
}

int sysfs_add_file(struct kernfs_node *parent, const struct attribute *attr,
           bool is_bin)
{
    return sysfs_add_file_mode_ns(parent, attr, is_bin, attr->mode, NULL);
}

int sysfs_add_file_mode_ns(struct kernfs_node *parent,
               const struct attribute *attr, bool is_bin,
               umode_t mode, const void *ns)
{
    struct lock_class_key *key = NULL;
    const struct kernfs_ops *ops;
    struct kernfs_node *kn;
    loff_t size;

    if (!is_bin) {
        ...
    } else {


        struct bin_attribute *battr = (void *)attr;
         ...
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, trying to do so now

Comment: I should note, I've created modules that use binary file attributes, I just don't see how the kernel is linking the struct properly downstream

Comment: `Isn't this pointing to a struct attribute at this point` - Yes, it is. But as `attr` field of type `struct attribute` is the **first field in the container** struct `bin_attribute`, a pointer to the field is at the same time a pointer to the container. So, `battr` is actually points to the `bin_attribute` structure you pass to `sysfs_create_bin_file` function.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That's a trick to C pointers I did not put together (despite knowing the prerequisite information), thank you. Would you mind posting as a solution so I can mark as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line

```
stuct bin_attribute *battr = (void*)attr;
```

correctly obtains pointer to the `bin_attribute` structure from the pointer to its **first field** `attr` of type `struct attribute`.

---

Normally, Linux kernel developers tend to use `container_of` macro for obtaining pointer to the structure type knowing pointer to its field. More "canonical" way for the transformation above would be:

```
stuct bin_attribute *battr = container_of(attr, struct bin_attribute, attr);
```

(In this call the first `attr` argument refers to the *pointer*, and the third `attr` argument refers to the *field's name*).